Moving features of different geometries at the same time in QGIS
In QGIS 3.34 I would like to move a point feature and a polygon feature at the same time.
The polygon is a round buffer around a point. I am only able to edit the point and polygon one after the other. However, when doing so, the point feature is no longer centered in the center of the buffer.
Creating centroids for the buffer feature does not help either, as the buffer is often split by intersections with municipal boundaries.

I selected the point feature and the buffer features together (which was working) and then tried to move both via the "move object" button but that did not work.

You could use the 'Translate' tool, available in the processing toolbox.
Work out the difference between the x and y value of your point and the location of where you want to move it, e.g. 500 metres along the x-axis, -200 metres along the y-axis. Then select your point and in the Translate gui select your point layer as the input and tick 'Selected features only'.:

Then select your polygon features and do the same again using exactly the same offset values for the polygon layer.
This will create temporary layers, so copy the newly generated features into your original layers, then delete the original features.
--EDIT--
Better still, the use the expression builder to work out the offsets for you. In the gui, select the button to the right of the offset field, and click 'edit'. In the expression builder, add the following for the x offset, adding your values where indicated:
NewXCoordinate - x(@geometry)

And the same for y:
NewYCoordinate - y(@geometry)


I moved the point feature 500 m along the x-axis and tried to move the polygon feature to the new x-coordinate of the moved point feature by using the expression builder. However, I do not know the correct syntax.

You don't need to use the expression builder, that was just an extra suggestion in case you didn't want to work out how far you need to move it. If you moved the point 500m along the x-axis, just do exactly the same to the polygon.
